# When does && mean 'forwarding reference'?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

When compiled, the following code causes this error:

> 'Container::Wrapper::Wrapper(S)': member function already
>   defined or declared

Does the compiler think `S&&` in the constructor of `Wrapper` is a forwarding reference?

```
template<typename T>
struct Container
{
    template<class S>
    struct Wrapper {
        S obj;
        Wrapper(S&& obj) : obj(std::forward<S>(obj)){}
        Wrapper(const S& obj) : obj(obj){}
    };

    template<class S>
    void push_back(S&& obj) {
        void *storage = malloc(sizeof(Wrapper<S>));
        new (storage) Wrapper<S>(std::forward<S>(obj));
    }
};

struct Foobar{};

int main()
{
    Container<Foobar> cont;
    Foobar foobar;
    cont.push_back(foobar);
    return 0;
}
```

Looking at an example from [here](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers), I don't understand how what I'm doing is any different:

```
template <class T, class Allocator = allocator<T> >
class vector {
public:
    ...
    void push_back(T&& x);       // fully specified parameter type ⇒ no type deduction;
    ...                          // && ≡ rvalue reference
};
```

**Edit:**
The solution to this issue was to modify `push_back` to remove the reference from the type being used to instantiate the `Wrapper`:

```
template<class S>
void push_back(S&& obj) {
    typedef std::remove_reference<S>::type U;
    void *storage = malloc(sizeof(Wrapper<U>));
    new (storage) Wrapper<U>(std::forward<S>(obj));
}
```

Comment: "Universal" references need to use a *deduced* template parameter.

Comment: The Standard term is now _forwarding_ reference. @KerrekSB It can also be a deduced `auto` type.

Comment: `S` in `Wrapper(S&& obj)` is not deduced when calling the constructor, only when defining the object `Wrapper<S>`. Therefore, it is an rvalue reference, not a forwarding reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no universal references involved it the implementation of `Wrapper`. The only universal reference in your code is `Container<>::push_back`'s parameter.

When you call `cont.push_back(foobar);`, parameter `S` of `push_back` is deduced as `Foobar &`.

Later you attempt to instantiate your `Wrapper<S>` with `S == Foobar &`. Reference collapsing rules dictate that in `Wrapper`'s constructor parameter declarations `S &&` turns into `Foobar &` and `const S &` also turns into `Foobar &`.

This means that you end up with two supposedly "overloaded" `Wrapper::Wrapper` constructors, which have identical signatures. This is the reason for the  error message you observe.

If you attempt to instantiate `std::vector` with a template argument of lvalue reference type, you will run into exactly the same problem for its `push_back` overloads. However, with such an attempt compilation will typically fail miserably for other reasons, well before it gets to `push_back` overloads.

A more distilled example would look as follows

```
template <typename T> struct MyVector {
  void foo(T &&) {}
  void foo(const T &) {}
};

int main() {
  MyVector<int &> v;
}
```

and will produce the same error.

The fairly non-obvious part here is that `const T &` with `T = U &` actually becomes `U &` and not `const U &`. But that's indeed the case.

Comment: Ok...making more sense now. `assert(std::is_same<S, Foobar&>::value)` passes(in the body of push_back) where I thought I was dealing with `assert(std::is_same<S, Foobar>::value)`